# Position the Image at the bottom of a div

Tags: css

How do i position the image at the bottom of the section regardless of the height. I did try position relative and absolute but it didnt go well. pardon my english, i hope screenshots and live url will explain better.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VrxdKe

HTML

```
  <section class="green fifty">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <h1>
    Test Test Test
    </h1>
      <img src="http://www.quanmax.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/test.png" />
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="blue fifty">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <h1>
    Test Test Test
    </h1>
      <img src="http://www.quanmax.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/test.png" />
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS

```
  .green {
    background: green;
  }

  .blue {
    background: blue;
  }

  .fifty {
    height: 50vh;
    max-width: none;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }

  .inner-content {
    padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;
    display: table-cell;
  }
```

Screenshot to explain better: http://prntscr.com/he3jxl

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't it go well? What happened when you tried positioning?

Comment: On which browser you are testing?

Comment: Using `position: absolute;` --> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YELvap

Comment: Yeap position absolute worked! earlier when i tried it, i got my position relative somewhere else, I added 

position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    margin-right: -250px;

just to center align the image. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### `absolute` Positioning

Using `absolute` positioning on nested `img` element.

```
/* Additional */
.inner-content img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* adjust to suit requirements */
}
```

**Summary:**

1. The nested child element should be positioned `absolute`
2. Adjust offset `bottom` property value as per requirements
3. The containing parent element must be positioned `relative`
   (*requirement*)

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.green {
        background: green;
      }

      .blue {
        background: blue;
      }

      .fifty {
        height: 100vh; /* adjusted for the sake of demonstration */
        max-width: none;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
      }

      .inner-content {
        padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;
        display: table-cell;
        position: relative; /* additional (required) */
      }

/* Additional */
.inner-content img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* adjust to suit requirements */
}
```

```html
<section class="green fifty" style="height: 200vh;">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <h1>
    The sibling image is positioned <code>absolute</code>
    </h1>
    <img src="http://www.quanmax.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/test.png" />
  </div>
</section>
<section class="blue fifty">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <h1>
    The sibling image is positioned <code>absolute</code>
    </h1>
    <img src="http://www.quanmax.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/test.png" />
  </div>
</section>
```

[CodePen Demonstration](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YELvap)

#### `table-cell` Display on Additional Containing Element

Using `table-cell` display on additional nested element wrapping `img`.

```
/* Additional */
.inner-content_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 100vh; /* adjust to suit requirements */
}
```

**Summary:**

1. Wrap `img` in a containing element and display `table-cell`
2. Adjust height property value of additional containing as per requirements

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
.green {
        background: green;
      }

      .blue {
        background: blue;
      }

      .fifty {
        height: 100vh; /* adjusted for demonstration */
        max-width: none;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
      }

      .inner-content {
        padding:20px 20px 0px 20px;
        display: table-cell;
      }

/* Additional */
.inner-content_cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 100vh; /* adjust to suit requirements */
}
```

```html
<section class="green fifty">
  <div class="inner-content">
  <h1>
  The sibling element is displayed <code>table-cell</code>
  </h1>
   <div class="inner-content_cell">
    <img src="http://www.quanmax.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/test.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="blue fifty">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <h1>
    The sibling element is displayed <code>table-cell</code>
    </h1>
    <div class="inner-content_cell">
      <img src="http://www.quanmax.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/test.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[CodePen Demonstration](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPjXZx)

Answer (score 0):

The following code has used position relative & absolute.
It's working fine regardless of the height.

```css
.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.fifty {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.inner-content {
  padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
}

.inner-content img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="green fifty">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <h1>
      Test Test Test
    </h1>
    <img src="http://www.quanmax.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/test.png" />
  </div>
</section>
<section class="blue fifty">
  <div class="inner-content">
    <h1>
      Test Test Test
    </h1>
    <img src="http://www.quanmax.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/test.png" />
  </div>
</section>
```

For any further details of explanation. feel free to comment.